# What does the @ in the permission column mean?

Tags: mac-osx

`drwxr-xr-x@ 13 me  staff   442 Dec  3 04:57 projects`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's undocumented from what I've found in the past - however it means that the object has extended attributes.  Here is what I found when I looked a few months ago: http://forthescience.org/blog/2007/12/11/macosx-leopard-extended-ls/

Comment: +1 interesting, wonder if they are doing that to stop OSX from scattering .DS_Info files all over.

Comment: That's an interesting thought.  I know I still deal with pesky .DS_Info files all the time.

Comment: Here is documentation on how to disable it: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1629

Comment: The .DS_Store creation, I mean.

Comment: hey! my blog! :)

Answer (score 1):

From "man ls"

```
The following options are available:
-@      Display extended attribute keys and sizes in long (-l) output.

The Long Format
 If the -l option is given, the following information is displayed for each
 ...
 If the file or directory has extended attributes, the permissions field
 printed by the -l option is followed by a '@' character.  Otherwise, if the
```